# RichTextBox TextChanged gets called when Page initialises

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF RichTextBox and when the user types something into it I want to detect this and call a function.

The function checks all the other controls on my Page to see if they are all selected and then activates a NEXT button. (I'm building a questionaire)

The problem I'm having is that when the Page initialises when my program starts up, the RichTextBox TextChanged event is called and other controls (ComboBoxes) are not yet initialised and the program bombs out.

How can I stop the TextChanged event from getting called on start up??  Or how can I handle this situation?

```
public PageFaultReport()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void RichTextBox_DescribeProblem_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ActivateNextIcon();
}

private void ActivateNextIcon()
{
    ComboBoxItem OperatingSystem = (ComboBoxItem)Combo_OS.SelectedItem;
    ComboBoxItem Version         = (ComboBoxItem)Combo_Version.SelectedItem;

    TextRange textRangeDetailedSteps = new TextRange(RichTextBox_DescribeProblem.Document.ContentStart, RichTextBox_DescribeProblem.Document.ContentEnd);
    int detailedStepsLength = textRangeDetailedSteps.Text.Length;

    if (YesNo_Permission.Selected == true && OperatingSystem != null && Version != null && YesNo_HardwareKey.Selected == true && YesNo_ExceededConnections.Selected == true && detailedStepsLength > 0)
    {
        Image_Forward.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:InstallerToolkit.UserControls" x:Class="InstallerToolkit.Pages.PageFaultReport" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="525" d:DesignWidth="1050"
  Title="PageFaultReport"
  Loaded="Page_Loaded">

<RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBox_DescribeProblem" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="93" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="894" Margin="75,295,0,0" TextChanged="RichTextBox_DescribeProblem_TextChanged" >
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph LineHeight="1"/>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your Page's constructor and the XAML portion for your RichTextBox?

Comment: You could query the `sender` or TextChangedEventArgs?

Comment: Check weather you are registering textchange event in the code before assigning text to this RichTextBox

Comment: See my EDIT.  The constructor calls InitialiseComponent which seems to call the TextChanged event.

Comment: @CodeBlend What do I check sender or TextChangedEventArgs for???

Comment: I would imagine that if you set a breakpoint and check it on page load and then check it again on a user click you should see differences in the sender and/or event args. You could then check this to pick up a user click

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent it by Setting a Bool value,

```
bool isFired = false;

private void RichTextBox_DescribeProblem_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

       if(isFired == false)
       {
         e.handled = true;
         isFired = true;
       } 
       else
       {
         ActivateNextIcon();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, yeah, you have some value set in XAML so it should be initialized. I usually deal with it similar to Sajeetharan, but check for `IsLoaded` instead of setting custom flag:

```
private void RichTextBox_DescribeProblem_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsLoaded) return;

    //whatever
}
```

In my case `this` is a `Window` but you can take some parent or `RichTextBox` itself.